# Makefile that works on file pairs

Tags: bash, makefile

I am working on a Makefile to maintain a workflow. The main part of the workflow requires a programs that can work on pairs of files. I have a directory of the raw data with the raw file pairs. Each pair has a name followed by `_1.txt` or `_2.txt`. The first step of the program should run a QC pipeline that requires both of these pairs and produces new pairs. The command looks like this:

`run_qc.sh -in1 file_1.txt -in2 file_2.txt -out1 file_1.qc.txt -out2 file_2.qc.txt`

The second step takes the qc'd files and combines them into a final result like this:

`run_analysis.sh file_1.qc.txt file_2.qc.txt > file_result.txt`

I want the program to run for all pairs that have the same prefix (*i.e.,* `file` in the above example is the prefix). The best I have come up with so far is to just look at one of the file pairs then assume that everything for the second works and to make a dummy rule that doesn't do anything to fill out the dependency graph. It looks like this:

```
RAW_DIR = data/raw
QC_DIR = data/qc
ALL_FILES = $(wildcard $(RAW_DIR)/*.txt)
QC_FILES = $(patsubst $(RAW_DIR)/%.txt, $(QC_DIR)/%.qc.txt, $(ALL_FILES))

qc : $(QC_FILES)

$(QC_DIR)/%_1.qc.txt : $(RAW_DIR)/%_1.txt
    bash run_qc.sh -in1 $< -in2 $(patsubst $(RAW_DIR)/%_1.txt, $(RAW_DIR)/%_2.txt, $<) -out1 $@ -out2 $(patsubst $(QC_DIR)/%_1.qc.txt, $(QC_DIR)/%_2.qc.txt, $@)
 
 
$(QC_DIR)/%_2.qc.txt : $(RAW_DIR)/%_2.txt
    @echo
```

This solution seems to work alright, but I think there is something that I am missing to make the workflow more maintainable without the extra useless target. I am also assuming, that once I have this step figured out, it would be a lot easier to combine the results into the final analysis step.

So, ultimately my question is, how can I make a single rule that is aware of these file pairs when I may have to run this on many file pairs?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes that your make is GNU make. It also assumes that the final `*_result.txt` files go in the same directory as the `qc` files. Adapt the corresponding recipe if it is not the case.

"*This solution seems to work alright*": it cannot work at all because your recipe does not translate into valid shell syntax. There are several issues with your Makefile:

1. You apparently think that make recipes are written in "make language". This is not really the case and you cannot use any make construct you want in recipes. Recipes, after very few specific translations by make (the expansion), are handed to the "shell", which is `sh` by default (but this can be changed). Your recipe does not translate into valid `sh` syntax (`RAW1 = $<` should be `RAW1=$<`, for instance). So, you should see errors (e.g., *RAW1: command not found*) when the shell tries to execute your recipe.
2. All lines of a recipe are executed by a different shell. You cannot assign a variable in a line and use it in another... unless you write your complete recipe as a single line of shell (using the `;`, `&&`,  `||`,... shell operators to separate the commands). Note that you can still write your recipe on several lines, if you wish, with line continuation, that is, by adding a backslash at the end of each line except the last.
3. make expands the recipes before passing them to the shell. So if you want a `$` sign to be passed to the shell you must escape it (`$$`) such that, after expansion by make, it becomes `$`.
4. `patsubst` takes 3 parameters, not two. But you don't need it. The `$*` automatic variable is your friend.
5. If your make is GNU make there are ways to indicate that a single execution of a recipe produces more than one target: grouped targets. In pattern rules with several targets GNU make considers the targets as grouped targets, the recipe is executed only once to build all. With recent versions of GNU make you can even make this explicit in non-pattern rules:

```
foo bar &: baz
    command-that-builds-foo-and-bar
```

So, with GNU make, your Makefile should be something like:

```
RAW_DIR   := data/raw
QC_DIR    := data/qc
PREFIXES  := $(patsubst $(RAW_DIR)/%_1.txt,%,$(wildcard $(RAW_DIR)/*_1.txt))
QC_FILES  := $(patsubst %,$(QC_DIR)/%_1.qc.txt $(QC_DIR)/%_2.qc.txt,$(PREFIXES))
TARGETS   := $(patsubst %,$(QC_DIR)/%_result.txt,$(PREFIXES))

.PHONY: qc all
all: $(TARGETS)
qc: $(QC_FILES)

$(QC_DIR)/%_1.qc.txt $(QC_DIR)/%_2.qc.txt: $(RAW_DIR)/%_1.txt $(RAW_DIR)/%_2.txt
    run_qc.sh -in1 $(RAW_DIR)/$*_1.txt -in2 $(RAW_DIR)/$*_2.txt -out1 $(QC_DIR)/$*_1.qc.txt -out2 $(QC_DIR)/$*_2.qc.txt

$(QC_DIR)/%_result.txt: $(QC_DIR)/%_1.qc.txt $(QC_DIR)/%_2.qc.txt
    run_analysis.sh $^ > $@
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I made a few edits to make the example work... It should run now, assuming you have scripts with the correct names. This is what I get for rushing a sample of the error... This seems to work very well! I appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm not sure it's accurate to say that make recipes _are_ shell scripts; I would say they _need to generate_ valid shell scripts. The literal makefile content doesn't go through a shell parser, after all; they're read by `make`, a separate C program with its own parse phase, which then invokes whichever shell is specified in the `SHELL` make variable. It would be confusing and not necessarily very useful to do so, but one _could_ set `SHELL` to something that isn't a POSIX-family shell language at all, f/e.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right and I slightly modified my answer accordingly to mention that _by default_ the recipes are `sh`  scripts. Note however that _shell_ seams to be the more or less standard vocabulary used in POSIX and in GNU make  manual for whatever executes the recipes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy And yes, the recipes can be modified by make before passing them to the shell but I would not really conclude from this that they are written in another language: _However, recipes are meant to be interpreted by the shell and so they are written using shell syntax. The make program does not try to understand shell syntax: it performs only a very few specific translations on the content of the recipe before handing it to the shell_ ([GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recipe-Syntax)).

Comment: Still, I wouldn't call `RAW1=$<` valid shell syntax until _after_ `make` replaces `$<` with a specific value. There are several other places where make and shell syntax conflict (`$$` having different meanings among them), so my interpretation is that makefiles _really are_ written in a "make language" (albeit in such a way that when evaluated they need to generate output in shell language), and that the contrary statements are flatly wrong.

Comment: I see your point and tried to find a intermediate between accuracy and reluctance to let newcomers think that the recipes are written in make language. Not 100% sure I succeeded, though.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I certainly follow it! As mentioned above, I modified my original makefile into a runnable example to keep the question more concise. Nonetheless, this explanation of how make processes the files makes it much clearer to think about.

Comment: @Grimey Yes, I saw your edits. I left the initial explanation because it may help others. Note that editing your question up to the point where parts (or all) of the existing answers become irrelevant is not necessarily a good idea. It is better to edit your questions mostly to add the missing information that comments ask for.